# Simple send form for whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple form to send messages to a specific WhatsApp contact. I was trying to use a javascript, but I'm not getting it, the link is not going the way I want.

I'm using the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#send-message-whatsapp').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const $form = $("#send-message-whatsapp");
    const phone = '559999999999';
    const nome = $form.children('input[name="nome"]').val();
    const email = $form.children('input[name="email"]').val();
    const wpp = $form.children('input[name="wpp"]').val();
    const cep = $form.children('input[name="cep"]').val();
    const rua = $form.children('input[name="rua"]').val();
    const bairro = $form.children('input[name="bairro"]').val();
    const complemento = $form.children('input[name="complemento"]').val();
    
    const action = "https://wa.me/" + phone + "?text=" + nome + email + wpp + cep + rua + bairro + complemento;

    $form.attr('action', action);
    $form.attr('target', '_blank');
    $form.submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="send-message-whatsapp">

    <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu nome" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="nome">Nome completo</label>
  </div>
    
    <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="inputEmail">Seu E-mail</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text"name="wpp" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="wpp">Seu Número/WhatsApp</label>
  </div>
  
   <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="cep" name="cep" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu cep" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="cep">Seu CEP</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="rua" name="rua" class="form-control" placeholder="Sua Rua" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="rua">Nome da sua Rua</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="bairro" name="bairro" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu Bairro" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="rua">Bairro</label>
  </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" name="complemento" class="form-control" placeholder="Complemento" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="rua">Complemento</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

When I click on send the link does not go with the filled texts ..

**This form will be used to capture leads in an internal campaign for my company.**

Also if you have any solution in PHP I would like to know if you can help me ...

*Sorry my english, i'm using translator...*

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " the link does not go with the filled texts .."? Is there an error message?

Comment: Exemple: https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=559999999999?text=*mytextform* but just the number goes without the information filled in..

Comment: @EvertonGouveia try https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=559999999999&text=hello (replace the second ? with &)

Comment: Tried encoding the text for using it inside of URL parameters? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use serializeArray to get an array of the fields (convert it to object), then make an array for the text and then join() it with your separator, plus dont forget encodeURIComponent else user could inject own params.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#send-message-whatsapp').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const $form = $("#send-message-whatsapp");

    const phone = '559999999999';

    // get object i.e {key: 'value'} of form
    let data = {}
    $form.serializeArray().forEach(v => data[v.name] = v.value)

    // make the ?text= payload, 
    // - could use .filter() here too if you dont want empty values
    const text = [
      data.nome,
      data.email,
      data.wpp,
      data.cep,
      data.rua,
      data.bairro,
      data.complemento
    ].join(' - ') // change to what you want sep to be

    // make the url
    const action = "https://wa.me/" + phone + "?text=" + encodeURIComponent(text);
    console.log(action)

    /*
        $form.attr('action', action);
        $form.attr('target', '_blank');
        $form.submit();
    */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="send-message-whatsapp">

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu nome" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="nome">Nome completo</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="inputEmail">Seu E-mail</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" name="wpp" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="wpp">Seu Número/WhatsApp</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="cep" name="cep" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu cep" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="cep">Seu CEP</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="rua" name="rua" class="form-control" placeholder="Sua Rua" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="rua">Nome da sua Rua</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" id="bairro" name="bairro" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu Bairro" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="rua">Bairro</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" name="complemento" class="form-control" placeholder="Complemento" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="rua">Complemento</label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

As `data` is key value you could also do the following to create a nicer message:

```
$(function() {
  $('#send-message-whatsapp').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    ...

    // uppercase first letter of Key: value i.e:
    /* 
    [
      "Nome: ",
      "Email: ",
      "Wpp: ",
      "Cep: ",
      "Rua: ",
      "Bairro: ",
      "Complemento: "
    ]
    */
    let text = []
    $form.serializeArray().forEach(v => text.push(v.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.name.slice(1) + ': ' + v.value))

    // make the url, join text with a new line
    const action = "https://wa.me/" + phone + "?text=" + encodeURIComponent(text.join('\n'));
    
    ...
  });
});
```

Then your message will look like:

```
Nome: Loz C
Email: internet-way@example.com
Wpp: Don't know what this is
Cep: Don't know what this is
Rua: Don't know what this is
Bairro: Full of chavs
Complemento: It's ayyok
```

Comment: Error in:     $form.serializeArray().forEach(v => data.push(v.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.name.slice(1) + ': ' + v.value))
 - Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: There was a `...` in the code block in the answer - don't forget to copy the rest of the code. In this case, specifically the line `let data = {}`

Comment: @samueldple was by design, unrelavant code is above

Comment: recheck the code your prob not defining `const action` correctly as shown in my answer, it looks like your trying to use them as get params

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Tools/Document_parameters):

> Multiple query parameters are separated by `&` instead of the initial `?`.

The first URL parameter is denoted by a `?` at the end of the URL path. After that, additional parameters are given using `&`.

For example: `https://www.example.com?param1=a&param2=b`

As Deepak Kamat said, you may also wish to look into encoding your URL parameters.